# Gerar novo nome para a imagem durante upload - php

Tags: php, upload

Utilizo o código abaixo e funciona corretamente, porém preciso que durante o UPLOAD o nome da imagem seja alterado.

```
<?php require_once('conexao.php'); ?>
<?php
$cliente = $_GET['cliente'];
$cod = $_GET['cod'];

$uploaddir = "./clientes/".$cliente."/".$cod."/"; 

$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 

$imvfoto = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];       

$sqlgravar="INSERT INTO fotos(cod,cliente,foto) 
VALUES ('$cod','$cliente','$imvfoto')"; 
$resultadogravar = mysql_query($sqlgravar)
or die (mysql_error());



if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}

    include("resize-class.php");
    $resizeObj = new resize("/home/roteirodoimovelc/public_html/cp/clientes/".$cliente."/".$cod."/".$imvfoto."");
    // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(600, 450, 'exact');
    $resizeObj -> saveImage("/home/roteirodoimovelc/public_html/cp/clientes/".$cliente."/".$cod."/".$imvfoto."", 100);

?>
```

Como faço esta implementação para que a foto seja renomeada e gravada no servidor e também no banco de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta trocar estas linhas:

```
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 
$imvfoto = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
```

por

```
$imvfoto = "o nome que você quiser";
$file = $uploaddir . $imvfoto;
```

Se quiser gerar um ID unico e pegar a extensão do arquivo:

```
$imvfoto = uniqid('img_').pathinfo($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file = $uploaddir . $imvfoto;
```

Claro que você vai adaptar isso à lógica desejada, mas como você não definiu de onde vem o novo nome na pergunta, seria especulação.

De qualquer forma, precisa ver se isso faz sentido, pois bastaria usar o ID do banco como novo nome, por exemplo preenchendo de zeros. Assim ficariam 0000001, 0000002, etc, mesmo gravando o nome original no BD apenas como referência.

Comment: ele não pega a extensão

Comment: O exemplo atual na resposta que gera um ID unico, e pega a extensão.

Answer (score 3):

Voce pode usar **UNIX TIMESTAMP**

```
// Define o novo nome do arquivo usando um UNIX TIMESTAMP
$nome = time() . '.' . $extensao;
```

Para pegar a extensão use:

```
$extensao= $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Boa Tarde Gladison, quando eu trabalho com upload de imagem em qualquer linguagem além da preocupação de alterar o nome acho interessante você tratar a extensão para que não tenha futuros problemas com upload de arquivos que possam danificar o seu servidor.
Deste modo trabalho o código dessa maneira.

```
        //verifica que tipo de arquivo esta sendo enviado
        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);
        //altera o nome
        $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
        //define o caminho para qual a imagem será enviada
        $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;
        //efetua o upload
        move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Seja bem ao site Thiago.

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago, mas esta proteção já utilizo no Ajax que upa a foto para mim.

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini ajax nao protege nada, pois pode ser editado pelo cliente. A solução do Thiago é boa, só precisa lembrar de desabilitar o [mime/magic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) se for Apache, senão o que vale é o conteúdo, e não a extensão. Com mime/magic ligado, o Apache entende que um executável é executável mesmo se a extensão for .gif, por exemplo. Já vi invasão com PHP enviado por CMS, com extensão de imagem. Passou pelo filtro de extensão, mas o Apache executou como PHP. E o pior: o mime/magic vem LIGADO como default em muitas instalações.

Comment: Também acredito que o Ajax seja mesmo precário nessa proteção, e sim para essa função ser executada corretamente deve-se configurar o Apache.

Comment: @Bacco obrigado pela explicação! Vou ajustar o código.

Comment: Acha sem problemas, é uma saída com certeza considerável, uma melhoria ao código.
Sou sempre adepto a boas sugestões :)

Comment: @Bacco uma maneira que estou usando muito atualmente é a Encryption Class do CodeIgniter, onde você consegue encriptar nomes, dados e até parâmetros e depois resgata-los usando uma chave padrão sua.
Caso tenha interesse segue o link abaixo:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html

Answer (score -1):

Esse código abaixo pega as extensão e dá um novo nome mantendo a extensão original.

```
$data = date("d-m-Y")."-";
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

     $Fotos = $_FILES['file'];
     $Nome    = $Fotos['name'];

    // Pega extensão do arquivo
            preg_match("/\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp){1}$/i", $Nome, $ext);

            //  Retira a extensao do nome do arquivo
            $nome_sem_extensao = $Nome;
            $nome_sem_extensao = basename ($nome_sem_extensao,".gif");
            $nome_sem_extensao = basename ($nome_sem_extensao,".jpeg");
            $nome_sem_extensao = basename ($nome_sem_extensao,".jpg");
            $nome_sem_extensao = basename ($nome_sem_extensao,".png");
            $nome_sem_extensao = basename ($nome_sem_extensao,".bmp");

            //  Retira espaços em branco do nome do arquivo
            //$nome_banco = str_replace(" ","_",$nome_sem_extensao);

            //Gera um nome único para a imagem
            $novonomedaimagem = $data . md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
```